# What are the most generous constraints for positive semidefiniteness in this construction?

Tags: machine-learning

I am asking this in the context of MultiTask Learning applied to Gaussian Processes.

Suppose I have two isotropic RBF kernel functions $K^a(x,x')$ and $K^b(x,x')$ and $N$ distinct points $x_1, x_2, ..., x_N$. Consider the following $200 \times 200$ matrix, where $K^a_{i,j} = K^a(x_i, x_j)$ and $K^b_{i,j} = K^b(x_i, x_j)$, and $i,j = 1,2,...,100$:

$$M =  \begin{bmatrix}
K^a & C^T \\
C & K^b
\end{bmatrix}$$

This matrix has ones on its diagonal. What are the most generous constraints on $C$ such that M is positive semidefinite?

For reference, the RBF kernel is given by:
$$K(x,x') = \text{exp}\Big( \frac{||x - x' ||}{2\sigma^2}\Big)$$
(Thus the only difference between $K^a$ and $K^b$ is their $\sigma$ parameter.)